# Infinispan cache returning null object

Tags: caching, jboss, wildfly, infinispan

Getting NullPointer exception while put the values into cache using cache.put() method.

Environment:
Jboss 7.2

Here is the sample code I've written to reproduce the issue.

Configuration form standalone.xml file:

```
`<cache-container name="sampleCache" default-cache="default">
     <local-cache name="default"/>
</cache-container>`
```

Added dependencies in deploy descriptor file like

```
`<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
    <dependencies>
    <module name="org.infinispan.commons" /> 
    <module name="org.infinispan" /> 
    </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>`
```

Getting the cache object via @Resource from Java code

```
`import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.ejb.Singleton;
    import javax.ejb.Startup;

    import org.infinispan.Cache;


    /**
     * InfiniSpanJbossCache Implementation
     *
     */
    @Startup
    @Singleton
    public class InfiniSpanJbossCacheExample {

        @Resource(lookup="java:/jboss/infinispan/cache/sampleCache/default")
        private static Cache<String, String> cache;

        @PostConstruct
        public static void deploy(){        
        cache.put("test","inserted1element");   
        }
    }`
```

While trying to insert some values into cache(cache.put("","")) I'm getting the error, Did I miss any configs????

Comment: Hey, would you like to take a look at https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/blob/master/jboss-as7/README.md ?

Comment: Thanks @Diego, changed the cache object from static to instance variable and called in  a non-static method , it solved my issue...